# I'm looking for a JQuery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm looking for a JQuery tooltip like Stackoverflow's this one:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<span class="tooltip_display">Tooltip</span>
<div class="ttip">
  <div class="contents">Here goes contents...</div>
  <span class="note">(click here to close the box)</span> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ttip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #303030;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #303030;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #303030;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    -o-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #F45000, #FF8000);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F45000), to(#FF8000));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F45000', endColorstr='#FF8000', GradientType=0 );
    display: none
}
.contents {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight:bold
}
.note {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    width: 100%
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.tooltip_display').click(function() {
    $('.ttip').css({
        left: '20px',
        top: '50px'
    }).show(500)
});

$('.note').live('click',
function() {
    $('.ttip').hide(500);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/karMU/)

Comment: @French Boy I give a simple demo. but you can find more better from source given below.

Comment: Nice work. I fiddled it up for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkL5B/)

Comment: EDit your answer to add the code for hiding the tooltip

Comment: THere is a bug `$(this).hide(500);` should be `$('.ttip').hide(500);`

Comment: or `$(this).parent().hide(500);`

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use this one and find it quite customizable and practical : http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#tips you can then easily customize the css to get the same as stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would class StackOverflow's popup as more of a Modal Dialog than a Tooltip. I find this jQuery Modal Dialog the simplest to use:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/